# Wireless firmware is missing

Tags: wireless, firmware

I just installed Ubuntu 10.10 on my hp Pavilion dv5000.

It doesn't seen to recognise the wireless network and it says Wireless Networks device not ready (firmware missing).

Is there some kind of update that I can download? I would really like to get this problem fixed.

Output from `sudo lshw -class network`:

```
~$ sudo lshw -class network 
    *-network:0 
        description: Network controller 
        product: BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller 
        vendor: Broadcom Corporation physical id: 2 
        bus info: pci@0000:06:02.0 
        version: 02 
        width: 32 bits 
        clock: 33MHz 
        capabilities: bus_master 
        configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=64 
        resources: irq:21 memory:c0200000-c0201fff 
    *-network:1
        description: Ethernet interface 
        product: RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ 
        vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
        physical id: 6 
        bus info: pci@0000:06:06.0 
        logical name: eth0 
        version: 10 
        serial: 00:16:d4:04:8c:cf 
        size: 100Mbit/s 
        capacity: 100Mbit/s 
        width: 32 bits 
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation 
        configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=8139too driverversion=0.9.28 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.108 latency=128 link=yes maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
        resources: irq:22 
        ioport:a000(size=256) 
        memory:c0202000-c02020ff 
   *-network DISABLED 
        description: Wireless interface 
        physical id: 3 
        logical name: wlan0
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Comment: need "sudo lshw -class network" and "sudo lspci" information

Comment: This is what i get

Comment: :~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for nathan:
  *-network:0            
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:06:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=64
       resources: irq:21 memory:c0200000-c0201fff
  *-network:1

Comment: *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 6
       bus info: pci@0000:06:06.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 00:16:d4:04:8c:cf
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz

Comment: capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=8139too driverversion=0.9.28 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.108 latency=128 link=yes maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:22 ioport:a000(size=256) memory:c0202000-c02020ff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: wlan0

Answer (score 1):

It would appear you need to `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`

Manpage for Ubuntu: [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20Internet%20access)

additional information from linuxwireless [here](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#Ubuntu.2FDebian)

Instead of a computer restart, in a terminal issue the following commands:

`sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl` and

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

Note: Allow several seconds for the network manager to scan for available networks before attempting a connection.